# Как инициализировать RecyclerView

Tags: kotlin

Я только учусь. Android Studio последняя версия.
Делаю по примеру, последний шаг. Но при запуске приложения выходит сообщение (ошибка):

e: C:\RecyclerView_CardView\app\src\main\java\com\example\recyclerview_cardview\MainActivity.kt: (12, 5): Property must be initialized or be abstract.
**MainActivity сам код:**

```
package com.example.recyclerview_cardview

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var adapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>
    lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    val recyclerView : RecyclerView   <-----------------------как правильно написать ???????

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        layoutManager =  LinearLayoutManager (this )
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

        adapter = RecyclerAdapter()
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы нигде не присвоили переменной инстанс списка, который обычно можно достать  `findViewById`. (и для себя лучше начинать учиться сразу с compose, имхо)

Comment: А как правильно инициализирлвать RecycleView?